ssr flutter application 2 way binding feature
I'm building a flutter SSR application with springboot as backend.
is there an alternative in flutter for the two way binding feature in angular
i tried using providers but got this error
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
